# How to export a specific sheet from my workbook to separate workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export a specific sheet in the workbook to a separate workbook(.xlsx).

I can export as PDF.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Kill ("D:\MAT.pdf")
On Error GoTo 0

With Sheets("MAT")
   .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="D:MAT.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

The purpose is to attach it in an email, which I did successfully, but I want to be able to attach it as an Excel sheet.

Notes:

- Can the sheet be exported without being a "macro-enabled sheet"?

Comment: So what is your code so gar?

Comment: Here is the relevant part of the code:


=========================================
On Error Resume Next
Kill ("D:\MAT.pdf")
On Error GoTo 0

With Sheets("MAT")
   .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="D:MAT.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

=========================================

I Just want to be able to export it as an excel sheet instead of PDF

Comment: You shoukd edit your original question with pertinent information , not leave it in comments that may not be read.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Save_Worksheet(Worksheet_Name As String, Destination_Path As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheet_Name)

   ws.Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Destination_Path & "\" & ws.Name, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
   ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To save Sheet1 to D:

```
Sub Test()
  Save_Worksheet "Sheet1", "D:"
End Sub
```

Note: You will need to add error handling, etc.